# How to use custom getter method in Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, getter-setter

I noticed that for a property with a custom getter method

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,getter=isActive) BOOL active;
@end
```

both

```
BOOL b = myObj.isActive
```

and

```
BOOL b = myObj.active
```

can be used to get the value. In both cases the `isActive` method is called.

- Is there any difference between these two ways of getting the property value?
- What is the "recommended" way?

Comment: Lot's of info on this is in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220028/dot-syntax-vs-method-syntax-with-getter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between the two. You use a custom name when you want to break the established convention of `XYZ`+`setXYZ` in cases when the alternative names make more sense from the point of view of English grammar. For example,

```
if ([myRobot isActive]) {
    ....
}
```

reads better than

```
if ([myRobot active]) {
    ....
}
```

You could have declared your property as `isActive`, but then your setter would be `setIsActive`, which sounds slightly worse than `setActive`.