# Call Objective-c property that have the key-word "getter=isXXX"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

`UIButton` has a property `selected`, of which the declaration is
`@property(nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected`.

So which way is correct to call the property?

1. `button.selected`
2. `button.isSelected`
3. `[button isSelected]`

I know they're all ok in Xcode, so what's the point of `getter=isXXX`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dot syntax vs method syntax with getter=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220028/dot-syntax-vs-method-syntax-with-getter)

Answer (score 5):

The `getter=isSelected` bit defines the name of the getter method. That's why you would write `[button isSelected]` and not `[button selected]`. When you write `button.selected`, it will generate a call to `[button isSelected]`.

As for which is right? They're all valid, though I would prefer the `isSelected` variants because that is the declared getter, and it reads more naturally.

Comment: The inconvenient thing of using `[button isSelected]` is when I want to modify the "selected" property, I have to search twice for ".seleced" and " isSelected]". I don't use "selected" because maybe there would be too many result if my property's name is a common word..

Answer (score 1):

Programatically?  None really.  It's all about semantics and verbs.  "isSelected" fits in more with a boolean type (is or is not something, does or doesn't do something, etc).  `[button selected]` will not be valid.  This probably dates back to before the dot syntax was introduced, so really the dot syntax is the out of place part here.  The dot syntax "mistakenly" (not so much a mistake, but not in line with the property declaration) allows "selected" to keep it consistent with C and other languages.

Comment: Could you please say a little more detail about "keep it consistent with C and other languages", maybe an example? Thanks!

Comment: Objective-C didn't have dots at all originally.  Therefore when they added them, they decided to keep the property names the same for the getter and the setter since it would be easier to deal with (there isn't really a concept of "getters and setters" when dealing with a simple property)

Answer (score 0):

From http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html

> If you don’t like `property` default naming conventions, you can
>   change the getter/setter method names with the `getter=` and `setter=`
>   attributes. A common use case for this is `BOOL` properties, whose
>   getters are conventionally prefixed with *is*.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected
> ```
>
> Now you can access the property as:

```
instance.selected = YES;               // [instance setSelected:YES]
NSLog(@"%d", instance.selected);       // [instance isSelected]
NSLog(@"%d", [instance selected]);     // Error: method no longer exists
NSLog(@"%d", [instance isSelected]);   // Correct call for getter method
NSLog(@"%d", instance.isSelected);     //Also Correct
```

Comment: I don't have a Mac at hand, but `instance.isSelected` should also work

Comment: @Gon but keep in mind, that it only works because you declared it. Without the `getter=isXXX` it would not work. This may answer your actual question

Comment: You need to properly attribute and markup as quotation any material that you use verbatim from another source.

Comment: I have already marked it, so please don't try to edit the post

Comment: Do not roll back edits that add proper attribution to copied text. Wording copied from another site **must** be placed in blockquotes, in addition to having proper link citation ahead of that text. To do otherwise makes it seem like you wrote this, when you did not. Josh was correct in his edits here.

Answer (score -1):

From http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html with slight modifications:

> If you don’t like `@property`’s default naming conventions, you can
>   change the getter/setter method names with the getter= and setter=
>   attributes. A common use case for this is Boolean properties, whose
>   getters are conventionally prefixed with is. Try changing the property.

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected.
```

> The generated accessors are now called `isSelected` and `setSelected:`. Note that the public property is still called `selected`, and this is what you should use for dot-notation:

```
Car *honda = [[Car alloc] init];
honda.selected = YES;                // [honda setSelected:YES]
NSLog(@"%d", honda.selected);        // [honda isSelected]
NSLog(@"%d", [honda selected]);      // Error: method no longer exists
```

> These are the only attributes that take an argument (the accessor
>   method name)—all of the others are Boolean flags.